# javascript div updating rate

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple HTML/Javascript as below
But when I run it, the label is only updated once, when it is 99999, which is not my intended behavior. I want the label to update in "real time". Is there any way I can force it to redraw. I have tried to put it into a

```
notice.style.display = 'none';
notice.innerHTML = i
notice.style.display = 'block';
```

but it still doesnt work.
Thank you very much.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label id = "esperanto-notice"></label>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
      var notice = document.getElementById("esperanto-notice")
      for(var i =0; i<100000; i++){
        notice.innerHTML = i
        console.log(i)
      } 
      console.log("done")
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript tries to run all its inline code before updating the DOM, because the latter is slow. Your whole loop runs before the page updates a single time.

We can force the page to update:

```
for(var i =0; i<100000; i++){
    notice.innerHTML = i;
    notice.getBoundingClientRect(); // Force DOM update to get latest size
    console.log(i);
}
```

However, while the DOM is updating it still goes straight back to the JS to keep running the loop - this is updating faster than you can see and *still* appears to hang.

What you need to do is **pause the JS execution so that the page has a chance to update**.

We can do this with an asynchronous JS function - something that finishes the current JS block but that queues up a callback function to fire later (in this case after the user has seen it):

```js
var notice = document.getElementById("esperanto-notice");
var i = 0;

// Function to write the next value, increment, and queue up the next timeout
var nextFunc = function() {
  console.log(i);
  notice.innerHTML = i++;
  if (i < 100000)
    setTimeout(nextFunc, 16); // 16ms is 60FPS 
  else
    console.log('done');
}

// Start it off
nextFunc();
```

```html
<label id="esperanto-notice"></label>
```

Now the entire JS runs and `nextFunc` executes once. It also queues it up to fire again after 16ms, but until then it lets the browser update the page.

Each time `nextFunc` fires it uses [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to queue up the next execution, then the page has a frame to update (so users see it), then it fires again.

Modern browsers provide a function specifically to wait for the next frame: [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame):

```js
var notice = document.getElementById("esperanto-notice");
var i = 0;

// Function to write the next value, increment, and queue up the next timeout
var nextFunc = function() {
  console.log(i);
  notice.innerHTML = i++;
  if (i < 100000)
    // Request the next visible frame to continue
    requestAnimationFrame(nextFunc); 
  else
    console.log('done');
}

// Start it off
nextFunc();
```

```html
<label id="esperanto-notice"></label>
```

This is the best way unless you need to support old versions of IE (<=9), as `requestAnimationFrame` can handle any duration of frame (`setTimeout` can have issues if you have lots of jank).

Finally, this is where the new language keywords `async` and `await` can make your code easier. You can keep the loop and abstract the wait for the DOM to update. This next snippet only runs on modern browsers like Chrome and FX (but could use Babel or TypeScript to support IE):

```js
(async function() {
  var notice = document.getElementById("esperanto-notice");
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    notice.innerHTML = i;
    
    // Pass back to the DOM until the next frame
    await new Promise(r => requestAnimationFrame(r));
  }

  console.log('done');
})();
```

```html
<label id="esperanto-notice"></label>
```

Comment: Wow. It is a very comprehensive answer. It fits my needs perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Your loop works very fast and you're not able to see changes in real time. To reach your goal you should to make some timeout before increment counter. For example:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label id = "esperanto-notice"></label>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
      var notice = document.getElementById("esperanto-notice")
      var i = 0;
      var interval = setInterval(function() {
        notice.innerHTML = ++i;
        if (i === 100000)
          clearInterval(interval)
      }, 500);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically update happened quite fast and you are only seeing the final update on that div,

Try changing the for-loop to following to see the changes

```
  for(var i =0; i<100000; i++)
  {
    (function(i){ //wrapping the value of i in an IIFE so that it can be locked
      setTimeout( function(){
        notice.innerHTML = i
        console.log(i)
      } , i * 100); //i*100 is in milliseconds        
    })(i);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript [**setInterval**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and [**clearinterval**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp).

```html
<html>
<body>
    <label id="esperanto-notice"></label>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var notice = document.getElementById("esperanto-notice");
        var i = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            notice.innerHTML = i;
            i++;
            if(i >= 100000) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 100);
        
        
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop execute in `milliseconds` and you only get the last value of your loop. If you want it in real time just use `setInterval`

```js
var notice = document.getElementById("esperanto-notice")
var i = 0  
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(changeCounter,1000)  
function changeCounter(){
   i++
   notice.innerHTML = i
   if(i==10){
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId)
    console.log("done")
   }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <label id = "esperanto-notice"></label>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is running very fast actually in "real time" you are not able to see the numbers change on your screen. In order to do that you need the numbers to change slowly enough for you to notice. For that you can setTimeout and delay the update to the DOM.

```js
    var notice = document.getElementById("esperanto-notice")
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(innerI) {
            notice.innerHTML = innerI;
            console.log(innerI);
        }.bind(null, i), i * 100);
    }
    console.log("done")
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <label id="esperanto-notice"></label>
    
</body>
</html>
```